# Where can I ask "Installing/compiling from source" questions?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm sure everyone has seen some variation of this:

> I then tried compiling the latest X from sources but unfortunately I got these nasty compile errors.
>
> ```
> bunch of error messages here
> ```
>
> I'm really clueless about how this happened and how to tackle it.

Sometimes the solution is something simple like, *"You forgot to install Y library headers"* or *"You shouldn't use an array as if it's an int."*  In other cases, it might be something much more obscure or complex.

But I can't help but think in these cases, *"Why are you asking us about stuff you aren't **developing yourself**?"*.

Most of these, it seems, should be closed as either "Not about programming" or "Needs details or clarity" since the person asking really hasn't any idea what the code in question is supposed to be doing in the first place.

Is there a better place to direct those kind of questions?

Comment: Sounds like you should probably be using the support mechanisms provided by product X.

Comment: @Servy exactly. I don't think SO is the actual place to ask those, but I wanted to be more neutral on my point of view.

Comment: I would say close as off topic or if there is a dupe on the type of error like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix) you could mark it as a dupe.

Comment: @NathanOliver off topic and send them to SU? Or the "why isn't my code working"?

Comment: "Too localized" is not a valid close reason anymore, you have to suck it up.  You could act stoopid and pick the exact opposite, "Too broad".  A DV is always an option.

Comment: @Braiam Sorry I didn't quite convey myself accurately.  For those question I pick to broad or unclear not off topic.

Comment: _"why are you asking us about stuff you aren't developing yourself?"_ Because the page on "What topics can I ask about here?" includes "software tools commonly used by programmers". Maybe a note could be added that this doesn't include installation issues.

Answer (score 3):

> Why are you asking us about stuff you aren't developing yourself? ... Most of these, it seems, should be closed as either "Not about programming" or "Needs details or clarity" ...

Agreed.  IMHO:

- Questions about installing an *application* that the user did not develop and/or has no intention of *developing* themselves are off-topic and should be closed as *"Not about programming"*, **even when that installation involves building from source**.

  These are typically not about *programming*, but rather simply following a set of installation instructions.

  Depending on the exact nature of the question, Stack Exchange does offer a number of other technical sites where the question may be on-topic:

  - [Super User](//superuser.com)
  - [Unix & Linux](//unix.stackexchange.com)
  - [Ask Ubuntu](//askubuntu.com)
  - And [quite a few others](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-questionsperday)

  However, before asking for a question to be transferred to another site, or recommending that the user repost the question, please make sure to identify any issues that might need to be resolved, including, as mentioned *Details and Clarity*.  It's never fun to have your question closed, but it's even more frustrating when it happens after reposting on another site. Helping the user understand the possible issues and asking them to correct them before reposting can (hopefully) help prevent this.

  In addition to SE sites, as mentioned in the comments, the software or project's normal support path (e.g., GitHub repository) may be a better option in some cases.
- However, questions about installing a programming tool or library from source are on-topic.

Answer (score 2):

The real answer is "it depends". Questions that ask about compiling code which is achieved just by a few commands in a command line interface (such as "run `./configure`, `make`, and `make install`", as suggested by a user in chat) can be asked on [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour) or other OS-specific sites, per [NotTheDr01ds' answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297849/where-can-i-ask-installing-compiling-from-source-questions/429496#429496), as using a command line to run commands (rather than to write code) is something *users* do, not *programmers*.

With that being said, I think there are numerous premise problems with this question:

> Sometimes the solution is something simple like, "You forgot to install Y library headers" or "You shouldn't use an array as if it's an int." In other cases, it might be something much more obscure or complex.

I'm not sure I see issues with these examples. It sounds like these are good answers to the imagined questions.

> Why are you asking us about stuff you aren't developing yourself?

Stack Overflow does not forbid asking questions about code other people wrote. A majority of Stack Overflow questions that are otherwise on-topic would likely need to be closed if that were the case. Such users may not be *writing* the code themselves, but they *are* trying to *compile* the code themselves.

> Most of these, it seems, should be closed as either "Not about programming"

Questions that ask about compiling code which requires programming tools (e.g. compilers, IDEs, etc.) *can* be asked about on Stack Overflow, because compiling code in general is widely considered a programming task ([since at least 2007](https://xkcd.com/303/)), especially if it requires a programming tool to do so.

> or "Needs details or clarity" since the person asking really has no idea what the code in question is supposed to be doing in the first place.

That's not what "needs details or clarity" means. First, obviously the person asking the question doesn't know the answer, or everything there is to know about their question—otherwise they wouldn't need to ask in the first place!

Second, why do you think someone having a problem with compiling code "has no idea what the code is supposed to be doing in the first place"? It sounds to me like you're conflating two completely unrelated things.

"Needs details or clarity" is applicable to any question that doesn't have enough details or information presented in it to provide an answer or to understand what the person is asking. This could include compiling from source, sure, but it also applies to literally any question that could be asked here. It's not inherently more likely to apply to building from source questions any more than it is to any other question.