# Are questions on programming tools installation/configuration on-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope, close-reasons

I have seen several instances of questions that don't seem to be directly about programming. To be precise, they are about installing and configuring development tools - e.g. NS2, Cygwin, Visual Studio, etc. However, I didn't see any objections to such questions from the community. Are such questions on-topic? Aren't they better suited for Superuser.com?

Is it correct to flag to close these for being about "general computing"?

Comment: Questions about programming tools are **on-topic**. This gets asked all the time here on Meta. Let me look to see if there's an appropriate canonical question around here...

Comment: According to the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), you can ask about "software tools commonly used by programmers".

Comment: As long as it's "•a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development".

Comment: and provided that it doesn't ask us to "recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource".

Comment: Weird side note:The last 3 comments can all be read as one sentence.

Comment: ...and we laugh when people ridicule us as thinking with a "hive mind", and yet here we are...

Comment: Programming tools are on-topic. Software installation is a grey area however. Just because a text editor or IDE is used *for* programming, doesn't make "where do i download X and which Y dll do I need?" on-topic. Just IMO.

Comment: I'd like to see a definitive answer to this - or, at a minimum, some answers both ways so that people can vote on it.

Comment: @EJoshuaS here's the thing, though - there's an objectively correct answer based on established site policy. You could expect to see answers both ways if someone posted a new question asking "***should*** tool installation questions be on-topic", but since this three-year old question asks whether they **are** on-topic, that's a question that currently has one correct answer.

Answer (score 9):

To quote the [on-topic help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page (relevant part bolded for emphasis):

> if your question generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - **software tools commonly used by programmers;** and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

So, generally speaking, questions about using tools are definitely on-top. And the more specific they are to coding, the more on-topic they are - questions about achieving a certain result with your favorite IDE would definitely be on topic. Questions about configuring your operating system probably not so much, but YMMV. Questions about adjusting the height of your chair for maximum comfort while programming, definitely not.

Additionally, note the distinction between asking a question about a specific tool ("I am using IDE XYZ and want to configure it to do ABC) and asking for a recommendation for the tool, which is definitely off-topic, as explained by the close-reason:

> Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I agree with most of this, but I would still close a _"How do I install Visual Studio Code"_ as being off-topic. More often than not, the installation of the software isn't specific to programming software. Questions about _configuring_ an IDE? Gray area...

Comment: @Cerbrus: Why would that be a gray area?

Comment: @BoltClock: Depends on what you're configuring... An IDE's GUI styling / layout isn't exactly programming-specific. Run / debugger configuration on the other hand...

Comment: @Cerbrus: Why do these types of questions need to be fragmented exactly, as compared to installation questions (which depending on the question may indeed be basic computer literacy and not programming-specific)?

Comment: @BoltClock because it isn't specific to software developing. What's the difference between installing Firefox and Visual Studio Code? None, you just have to click Next, Next, Accept, Next, Next, Finish.

Comment: @Braiam: I'm asking about configuration questions only, hence "as compared to installation questions" which as I already acknowledged are "basic computer literacy".

Answer (score -9):

You can ask about tools commonly used by developers on many technology sites, because, as things are, those tools are also commonly used by people that aren't developers: browsers, package managers, installers, etc. In fact, if developers don't have authorization by the administrator of the system then they cannot install anything on said system, which is probably the defining criteria.

If, as part of my developing task, I need to do something that developers at my company aren't allowed to do, then it's not a task **unique to software development**. Installing tools on a system needs elevated privileges (unless you do something clever like installing them on your home directory), is not a task we do in our capacity as software developers but as system administrator. This is also why I don't believe that questions about [programs you are not developing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297849/where-should-be-asked-compiling-installation-issues) are on topic.

Comment: Disagree, different developers have different access right in their machines, why only consider *your* access rights?

Comment: @user000001 are you developing anything at that point? That's the whole issue: you are not being a developer. If I install visual studio to compile mariadb, am I being a developer? No, because I'm just following the developers instructions, not creating a thing. Otherwise, we have many developers in the industry.

Comment: But only developers will know the answer if noone else is using the software. Tha's why it should be on SO instead of SU.

Comment: Sometimes, as a developer, you need to install a tool to help in your development work. Installing tools _is_ part of your job. You don't suddenly become a sysadmin if you're installing Visual Studio.

Comment: If you're interested in making a case that the site's current policy should be changed, you'd likely be better off starting a new post to discuss your position. As it stands, this three year old question is asking what the existing policy states, which this does not address or align with.

Comment: @SamHanley I don't think policy is "set", since the same argument I'm doing *here* I did it over here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/371558/792066 So, the issue is whenever the ontopic page should be read as A||B||C||D or (A||B||C)&&D.

Comment: I don't agree that that's the issue - it's very clear from the way that it's written that the on-topic page is (A||B||C)&&D, which I think we agree about (?). But it seems like here, you're making the (somewhat unsupported) assumption that all tooling installation/configuration questions boil down to a lack of user permissions, and are using that to argue that all such questions aren't "unique to software development". That's a viewpoint that you can argue for, although I disagree - I'm just suggesting that reviving a years-old question may not be the most fruitful place to make this new case.