# Is `rm` less on-topic than `tr`?

Tags: discussion, scope, reopen-closed

Today, I saw this question being closed as off-topic:

[Can't delete file in /usr/bin on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51519623/cant-delete-file-in-usr-bin-on-mac)

The argument being that `rm -rf` qualifies as "general computing hardware and software" rather than "software tools commonly used by programmers".
In the comments, it was described as "general-purpose file-system manipulation".

In essence,
OP wrote a program, thought it made sense to store it in `/usr/bin`, then needed help to get back on the right track.
Other programmers may benefit from this question and its answer. Isn't that what SO is all about?

#### EDIT

In response to the argument that the question fails to satisfy the requirement (as quoted from the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)) "unique to software development":

Please note that the question involves a very specific folder. This folder is typically not accessed by common users; hence the restrictions on that folder. OP accessed the folder specifically because OP wanted to deploy software, developed by OP. To me, that's enough for the question to be "unique to software development."

The fact that the issue of deleting a file may be **trivial** to most of us, is irrelevant to the discussion. What may be trivial to you, can be helpful to others. Other *developers*, who stepped in the same pitfall of copying their own scripts into `/usr/bin`.

Comment: With my limited knowledge of Mac, that seems like more of a SuperUser question than a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: The question may very well be more suitable elsewhere (SuperUser, AskDifferent, and perhaps even Unix), but that alone doesn't make it off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: `Now does rm -rf sound like something the average non-programmer would use on a regular basis?` - if you're primarily using a linux or unix os, and you want to be efficient, then you would certainly use the console for many tasks including for removing files.

Comment: @l4mpi Thank you for your comment. I suppose I was being ignorant of non-programming power users there, so I decided to remove the middle paragraph from my question; it seems to be drawing attention away from the relevant arguments.

Comment: Programmers shouldn't limit themselves to Stack Overflow. I use Software Engineering, Super User, Server Fault, Ask Ubuntu and Unix & Linux on a regular basis to tackle problems I encounter while doing programming-related work.

Comment: The litmus test is: **and unique to software development**. That problem is *not* "unique to software development".

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's not a very good litmus test. There are many problems that are not unique to software development but are still on-topic questions. Lots of algorithm questions boil down to math, but that doesn't mean they should be closed and asked on any of the math oriented sites. This question is about using a tool commonly used by programmers for programming purposes, AFAICT that is still on-topic.

Comment: @TinyGiant: We've actually closed math problems **because they were not algorithm problems**. It is an *excellent* litmus test. If the question is basically pure math with no practical progamming component, then it is very much off topic.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well sure, a pure math question that has nothing at all to do with algorithms or programming is off-topic. That in no way proves your point: That all questions must only be applicable in a programming sense. If they could possibly be considered in any other sense whatsoever then they are not unique to software development and are therefore off-topic.

Comment: @TinyGiant: See [How do you detect where two line segments intersect?](//stackoverflow.com/q/563198) for an example of a post that was closed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ... a single bad actor does not a point prove.

Comment: @MartijnPieters OP's question _does_ have a practical programming component. I edited my question to make my point.

Comment: @RuudHelderman: You are really stretching the definition there, making assumptions about what other users might run into. It is also something non-programming IT support professionals could run into. It's not a practical programming problem.

Comment: @MartijnPieters In SO, we are continuously making assumptions about whether or not a question could be helpful to others. I think _that_ should be the litmus test: is it helpful for developers? It was to OP. And as for the support professionals (or whoever): why should we care if they are having the same problem?

Comment: So you're asserting that if someone could possibly encounter a problem while not programming, then that problem is inherently _"not a practical programming problem"_ even if it is being asked about in a programming context? @MartijnPieters

Comment: I mean, I could use an IDE for writing a novel, does that in turn mean that questions about the usage of an IDE are off-topic because the IDE can be used for something other than programming?

Comment: @RuudHelderman: that's a slippery slope. Lots of stuff is helpful to them. Is working out how to best be a software developer living on a boat helpful? Sure, but that very topic was 'sunk' early on, as that's also not unique to software developers.

Comment: @TinyGiant: Like programming on a boat? See [What is the boat programming meme about?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/14470). You can make anything on topic if you encounter a problem while programming, right?

Comment: Yeah... but how is a terminal command a boat? @Martijn

Comment: Strawmen  aside, you have still not made a convincing argument to support your assertion that any problem that could possibly be encountered in a non-programming context is inherently off-topic, even if the problem is encountered in a programming context. After all, an IDE is just a fancy text editor, and text editors can be used for many things that have nothing to do with programming, so by your assertion any question about encountering a problem with an IDE is inherently off-topic regardless of whether or not that problem was encountered in a programming context.

Comment: @MartijnPieters By no means am I trying to "stretch the boundaries". Let me put it this way. When "general computing hardware and software" (macOS) has an obscure feature (System Integrity Protection) that is blocking programming-related efforts (deleting a program you wrote from a folder meant to store programs), then that makes a good match for SO. Wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @RuudHelderman: no, I don't agree. The feature is not that obscure, and trying to delete from that folder is not specific to programming.

Answer (score 12):

Is deleting a file using the user tools included by default in all users systems a task unique to software development? I would say no.

Comment: That's like saying a question about a problem writing a program in a text editor that is included by default in all users systems is off-topic because that text editor could be used for so many other things.

Comment: @Braiam Thank you for your answer. I would like to argue that the question _is_ unique to software development. I edited my question to make my point.

Comment: @TinyGiant no, changing the font to bold is something that isn't unique to programming, adding a c++ hinter plugin *is*.

Comment: That would be a problem that is not applicable to programming _at all whatsoever_, not a problem that applies to programming but is applicable to other areas of expertise as well.

Comment: @TinyGiant just because I have a hammer, doesn't mean I'm a carpenter nor doing carpentry.

Comment: Your overly vague and irrelevant analogy makes no sense in context. If I _am_ a carpenter, does the fact that someone who is not a carpenter is using a hammer for a non-carpentry-related task preclude me from using my hammer for carpentry related tasks? No, that's nonsense.

Comment: @TinyGiant is not vague, nor irrelevant. Is not the tool that makes question on or off topic, **is what you are doing with said tool**.

Comment: Ok, so the OP of the question in question is using the tool for programming purposes, i.e. in your own words your point is moot?

Comment: @TinyGiant The OP is not using that tool for programming. Yes, they wrote a program, but that's not what they're asking about. They're asking how to delete that program file from the command line.

Answer (score 5):

Deleting a file is something that you're going to end up doing while programming. If I run into a problem deleting a file using my favorite operating system (not having a program delete it, but rather just hitting the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key or otherwise telling the OS to remove a file), in the course of programming, is a question about that problem on-topic for Stack Overflow?

I would say no. Here's why:

I have understood Stack Overflow's purpose (up until recently anyway) to be the accumulation of practical, answerable problems unique to software development.

Deleting files from a file system, while certainly something you will run into while developing software, is also something you'll run into while using a computer in general. Therefore, logically, the problem is not unique to software development.

- It is also not about software tools commonly used by programmers (as opposed to any other group of computer users).
- It is not about a software algorithm.
- It is not a specific programming problem.

... and that pretty much covers what's on the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page on the help center.

It also fails a key test on that same page:

> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.

The file delete functionality is certainly not used primarily for programming.

---

Now some have brought up some other hypothetical scenarios, like what if someone is using an IDE to do something other than software development, is a question about that IDE now off-topic?

I would say we can't make a sweeping generalization about that. It depends on the question asked. If the question is how to make some text bold in the IDE, that is likely to be off-topic, since it doesn't make much sense to make code bold. If the question is about problems installing a particular plugin (like say a Markdown editor plugin), then sure, it could be on-topic. The same rigor we ask for other questions should be applied of course.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Two concerns: (1) "Not used primarily for programming": dangerous argument; can be used equally well to ban the more versatile members of a programmer's toolchain, e.g. less, grep, git. Where's the boundary? (2) "Deleting files from a file system (...) is also something you'll run into while using a computer in general." The question involved a specific folder; delete functionality in general (`rm`) was primarily proof of OP's efforts. Not a coincidence that a programmer was having the problem; it's not something my mom would encounter cleaning up her photo album.